# Android Espresso - check if text doesn't exist in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have the code which checks if the row with text "Product" exists in `RecyclerView`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_list)).perform(scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText("Product"))));
onView(withItemText("Product")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

public static Matcher<View> withItemText(final String itemText) {
    checkArgument(!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemText), "itemText cannot be null or empty");
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
            return allOf(
                    isDescendantOfA(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)),
                    withText(itemText)).matches(item);
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is isDescendantOfA RV with text " + itemText);
        }
    };
}
```

**How to check if there is no row with provided text in all list from `RecylerView`?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try create a custom matcher to iterate `RecyclerView` items:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasItem(Matcher<View> matcher) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {

        @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has item: ");
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView view) {
            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
            for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getItemCount(); position++) {
                int type = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, type);
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
                if (matcher.matches(holder.itemView)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

And if you'd like to check if there's no row with specific text, you could do:

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_list)).check(matches(not(hasItem(hasDescendant(withText("Product"))))));
```

Comment: In checking if there's NO row with specific text, the method `hasItem()` can be omitted.

Comment: @JoVerM You're right if `perform()` is used. But `check()` is used here and it does things differently, it only checks for the views that are currently displayed on the screen, it doesn't scroll or loop through the list in this case. So `hasItem` is simply another way to check the list.

Comment: How awesome to put code (with only fun names, without classes)... Where should I get `hasItem` from?!

Comment: It's only a static function as an example, it can be placed wherever is convenient. In this example, it's being placed in the same file, and so `hasItem` can be called directly.

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible solution would be to not to restrict it to a `hasItem` functionality but to instead provide an generic walker through the adapter's items so that any iterable matcher could be used, such as `contains` or `empty`. Kotlin example:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
fun recyclerChildViews(matcher: Matcher<MutableIterable<*>>): BoundedMatcher<View?, RecyclerView> =
    object : BoundedMatcher<View?, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("RecyclerView child views: ")
            matcher.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Boolean =
            matcher.matches(sequence {
                val adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> =
                    recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
                for (position in 0..<adapter.itemCount) {
                    val holder = adapter.createViewHolder(recyclerView, adapter.getItemViewType(position))
                    adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
                    yield(holder.itemView)
                }
            })
    }
```

You would then have all iterable matchers able to be used. To use this version for the original question it would change to:

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_list)).check(matches(not(recyclerChildViews(hasItem(hasDescendant(withText("Product")))))))
```